# With request in sql doesn't work & recognize

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a problem with my request, the request doesn't recognized WITH(). I work on Ubuntu & MySQL, can I get help please!

```
DB::select(DB::raw("WITH liststudentsoff as (
        SELECT tbl_etudiants.*, tbl_cours.idCours FROM dependance_groupes
        inner join tbl_etudiants on tbl_etudiants.idStudent = dependance_groupes.studentID
        inner join tbl_cours on tbl_cours.groupID = dependance_groupes.groupID
        inner join tbl_formations on tbl_formations.idFormation = tbl_cours.formationID
        )
        SELECT * FROM liststudentsoff
        LEFT JOIN tbl_absences ON liststudentsoff.idStudent = tbl_absences.studentID AND liststudentsoff.idCours = tbl_absences.coursID
        WHERE liststudentsoff.idCours = ".$request->idCours." and liststudentsoff.formationID = ".$cours->formationID.""));
```

Error display:

```
    [previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'liststudentsoff as (
        SELECT tbl_etudiants.*, tbl_cours.idCours FROM ' at line 1 at /var/www/html/emarge-backoffice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:338)
```

Comment: Could you please share your error message with us so that we can help you more properly?

Comment: Maybe your MySQL version is 5.x? Maybe parameters inserted are string-type literals, empty or incorrect?

Comment: I had edit the first post, with the error.

The version of MySQL in Ubuntu is the v5.7.34. But in local with the same configuration the request worked perfectly, it's weird :/